# LINQ, заполнить вложенный объект по Id

Tags: c#, linq

Имеем два класса:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public BookCategory BookCategory { get; set; }
}

public class BookCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

помогите заполнить список книг категориями

```
var books = new List<Book>()
{
    new Book { Id = 1, BookCategory = new BookCategory { Id = 1 }  },
    new Book { Id = 2, BookCategory = new BookCategory { Id = 1 }  },
    new Book { Id = 3, BookCategory = new BookCategory { Id = 2 }  },
    new Book { Id = 4, BookCategory = new BookCategory { Id = 2 }  }
};
var categories = new List<BookCategory>
{
    new BookCategory { Id = 1, Name = "Первая категория" },
    new BookCategory { Id = 2, Name = "Вторая категория" }
};

List<Book> booksWithCategories = //linq;
```

**Update:**

я Хочу получить список объектов Book с заполненным BookCategory.Name

Comment: Зачем вам `Id`? Используется какая то `ORM` типа `EntityFramework` или `NHibernate`?

Comment: на классическом ado.net

Comment: Вы создали 6 разных экземпляров категорий, 4 - книг. В коллекции книг с категориями должны быть новые 4 книги или старые с перебитыми категориями? Мне лично сложно сообразить, нужна ссылочная целостность этого кода или нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с созданием новых книг:

```
  List<Book> booksWithCategories = books.Select(b => new Book()
  {
    BookCategory = categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == b.BookCategory.Id),
    Id = b.Id
  }).ToList();
```

Вариант с заполнением старых книг:

```
  books.ForEach(b => b.BookCategory = categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == b.BookCategory.Id));
  List<Book> booksWithCategories = books.ToList();
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что мне было нужно